# Can you add a color bar to plotly python with an assigned variable for the colorbar like in matplotlib?

Tags: python, plotly, scatter-plot, colorbar

Is it possible to add a color bar to a simple scatter plot? I have my data for the x and y axis, then would like to assign the color bar to an independent variable “z”. I cannot for the life of me figure this out or find any documentation to help me.

https://plot.ly/python/colorscales/ is no help for assigning a variable to the colorbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the documentation [here](https://plot.ly/python/line-and-scatter/#scatter-with-a-color-dimension) to help you.

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.plotly as py

import numpy as np

trace1 = go.Scatter(
    y = np.random.randn(500),
    mode='markers',
    marker=dict(
        size=16,
        color = np.random.randn(500), #set color equal to a variable
        colorscale='Viridis',
        showscale=True
    )
)
data = [trace1]

py.iplot(data, filename='scatter-plot-with-colorscale')
```

[image]